# How would I store related tabular data in mongoDB?

Tags: python, mongodb, beautifulsoup, nosql

I have scraped table data using BeautifulSoup from a site. [(This is the link for reference)](https://www.bseindia.com/corporates/Results.aspx?Code=533239&Company=PRAKASH+STEELAGE+LTD.&qtr=97.50&RType=). This is data pertaining to a single company.

It's scraped and obtained in the form of multiple lists as such:

```
['Type', 'Audited', 'Audited', 'Audited', 'Audited']
['Period Ending', '31-Mar-18', '31-Mar-17', '31-Mar-16', '31-Mar-15']
['No, of Months', '12', '12', '12', '12'] 
#-----------------------------------------------------------------------#   
['Net Sales', '466,34', '1,479,10', '5,551,24', '10,724,32']
['Other Income', '26,68', '185,81', '132,56', '121,20']
['Interest', '0,00', '0,00', '-286,76', '-361,95']
['Profit before Tax', '-2,482,68', '-1,513,02', '-805,38', '213,97']
['Tax', '75,04', '-0,95', '-9,07', '-73,37']
```

I'm fairly new to Mongo and I'm aware how data is stored in document-style format. But I'm confused as to how to approach this.

Right now I'm thinking, generate a collection in db for EACH company and store data per column something like:

```
companydata.insert({'Type':'Audited', 'Period Ending': '31-Mar-18', 'Net 
                                                         Sales':'466,34'})

companydata.insert({'Type':'Audited', 'Period Ending': '31-Mar-17', 'Net 
                                                         Sales':'1,479,10'})
```

but that's hardly a solution, let alone be an elegant one. There has to be a better way.

Answer (score 1):

For the data you have provided, I have made the assumptions that the lists are available as list of lists.
You can use the following code:

```
import pandas as pd
from pymongo import MongoClient

scraped_data = [['Type', 'Audited', 'Audited', 'Audited', 'Audited'],
['Period Ending', '31-Mar-18', '31-Mar-17', '31-Mar-16', '31-Mar-15'],
['No, of Months', '12', '12', '12', '12'],
['Net Sales', '466,34', '1,479,10', '5,551,24', '10,724,32'],
['Other Income', '26,68', '185,81', '132,56', '121,20'],
['Interest', '0,00', '0,00', '-286,76', '-361,95'],
['Profit before Tax', '-2,482,68', '-1,513,02', '-805,38', '213,97'],
['Tax', '75,04', '-0,95', '-9,07', '-73,37']]

conn = MongoClient(host="url/of/mongodb", port=27017)
db = conn["db_name"]
coll = db['collection_name']

columns = [elem[0] for elem in data]

frame_data = [elem[1:] for elem in data]

source = pd.DataFrame(data=frame_data)

transposed = source.T

mapper_dict={}

for i,elem in enumerate(columns):
    mapper_dict.update({i:elem}) 

final_result = transposed.rename(mapper=mapper_dict,axis=1).to_dict(orient="records")

coll.insert_many(final_result)
```

This would store the data as per your requirement

Comment: @akash if the answer worked for you, can you accept the answer by clicking the green tick below the upvote arrow.